# Submitting login form just refreshes the page

Tags: excel, vba

im trying to write a macro to open and log into a webpage to download a specific data set, however i'm stuck on submitting the login details.

Everything seems to work as intended, page opens up, details appear in relevant username/password boxes but then rather than signing me in the page just refreshes to blank. Cant for the life of me work out whats causing this to happen.

This is the website - https://www.caredata.co.uk/login_register.cfm

Here is my code -

```
Sub Opensite()
'open caredata URL and login
    Dim IEapp As Object, WebURL As String, HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
        Set IEapp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        WebURL = "https://www.caredata.co.uk/login_register.cfm"
    With IEapp
        .silent = True
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate WebURL
        Do Until IEapp.readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set HTMLdoc = IEapp.document
    End With
    With HTMLdoc.forms(0)
        .UserName.Value = "myusername"
        .Password.Value = "mypassword"
        .submit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not click the button `btn_signin`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried that initially but couldn't get the code to recognise the right button. How would the code for this actually look?

Comment: Can I see the code that you tried to get the button?

Comment: Fixed it, with an embarrasingly simple single line, .btn_signin.click.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself, no idea how I didn't manage to work this out originally. Working code -

```
   Sub Opensite()
    'open caredata URL and login
        Dim IEapp As Object, WebURL As String, HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
            Set IEapp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
            WebURL = "https://www.caredata.co.uk/customer_downloads.cfm"
        With IEapp
            .silent = True
            .Visible = True
            .Navigate WebURL
            Do Until IEapp.readyState = 4
                DoEvents
            Loop
            Set HTMLdoc = IEapp.document
        End With
        With HTMLdoc.forms(0)
            .UserName.Value = "username"
            .Password.Value = "password"
            .btn_signin.Click
        End With
        downloadfile IEapp, HTMLdoc
    End Sub
```